# Microfrontend with Single-SPA, Vite and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, vite, micro-frontend, single-spa

I have a Single-SPA project with a root app (port 9000) and a Vite-React app (port 9002). However, I'm not able to fetch the app through the root (localhost:9000).

## Root app

**index.ejs:**

```
<script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "single-spa": "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js",
        "react": "https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js",
        "react-dom": "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
      }
    }
  </script>
  <link rel="preload" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/single-spa@5.9.0/lib/system/single-spa.min.js" as="script">


  <% if (isLocal) { %>
  <script type="systemjs-importmap">
    {
      "imports": {
        "@org/root-config": "//localhost:9000/pi-root-config.js"

      }
    }
  </script>
  <% } %>
```

**root-config.js**

```
import { registerApplication, start } from "single-spa";

registerApplication({
  name: "@org/react-test",
  app: () => 
    import(
      /* webpackIgnore: true */
      "http://localhost:9002/src/main.jsx"
    ),
  activeWhen: ["/"]
});

start({
  urlRerouteOnly: true,
});
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const singleSpaDefaults = require("webpack-config-single-spa");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const orgName = "org";
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName,
    projectName: "root-config",
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    disableHtmlGeneration: true,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    // modify the webpack config however you'd like to by adding to this object
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: false,
        template: "src/index.ejs",
        templateParameters: {
          isLocal: webpackConfigEnv && webpackConfigEnv.isLocal,
          orgName,
        },
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:9000/'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.json', '.png', '.svg']
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

## Vite-React app

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import singleSpaReact from "single-spa-react";
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  errorBoundary(err, info, props) {
    return <div>This renders when a error occurs</div>;
  },
});

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles;
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  rollupOptions: {
    input: 'src/main.jsx',
    format: 'system',
    preserveEntrySignatures: true,
  },
  base: "http://localhost:9002",
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    origin: "http://localhost:9002",
  },
})
```

I did some research and I already removed react-refresh from .eslintrc.cjs, but it doesn't work. Does anybody know how to build a structure with Single-SPA + Vite + React?

Comment: I would just do `server: { port: 9002 }` in `vite.config.js` and remove `base`.  Then, upon registration, I would use a "bare identifier" for the mife module, something like `System.import('@myorg/someName')`.  Remember that you are using a root config created with `create-single-spa`, and that demands the use of `SystemJS`.  You cannot use the regular dynamic `import()` call, as I understand it.

Comment: It's not possible to use SystemJS with Vite, only with WebPack.

Comment: Are you saying that Vite cannot produce SystemJS modules?  In other words:  Is rollup unable to produce SystemJS modules?  [This article](https://weshatch.com/content/posts/2021-02-09-systemjs-as-rollup-runtime/) seems to differ.

Comment: At least with Single-SPA I was not able to use it, I've tried but even the example they give here: https://single-spa.js.org/docs/examples does not include SystemJS. This is the repository of their Single-SPA + Vite project https://github.com/joeldenning/vite-single-spa-example

Comment: Anyway, the error it throws says "react-refresh cannot detect preamble"

Comment: Sorry, forgot about you.  I am no expert with Vite + Single-Spa, but I'm in the process of learning.  I blog about my learnings [here](https://webjose.hashnode.dev/series/single-spa-and-svelte).  See if anything there helps you out.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! I'll take a look at your website.

Answer (score -1):

Coincidentally, I just published [this article](https://webjose.hashnode.dev/vite-plugin-single-spa-vite-projects-made-single-spa-compatible-with-one-plug-in) that deals with the *"@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong"* error.

The short answer is a workaround:  Disable HMR.  In `vite.config.ts`:

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    hmr: false
  }
})
```

This, unfortunately for you, is for **Vite** server, not **webpack**.

A quick search for webpack revealed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121991/webpack-disable-hmr), and the first answer suggests doing this to the webpack configuration:

```js
{
  devServer: {
    hot: false, // disable HMR
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

See if this works for you.